# Indexing list with arrays from another array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a main list:

```
mainlist= [
        np.array([[ 604., 1464.],
                  [ 604., 1472.]]), 
        np.array([[ 612., 1483., 1455.],
                 [ 612., 1483., 1461.]]), 
        np.array([[2062., 2133.],
                [2063., 2133.],
                [2064., 2133.],
                [2065., 2133.],
                [2066., 2133.],
                [2067., 2133.]]),
       np.array([[769., 784., 783.],
                [770., 784., 783.],
                [771., 784., 783.],
                [772., 784., 783.],
                [773., 784., 783.]]) 
        ]
```

And an index array like:

```
index = np.array([[0, 1],
               [1, 0],
               [2, 1],
               [2, 3],
               [2, 4],
               [3, 1],
               [2, 2],
               [3, 1]])
```

where the first column is the index of the array of mainlist , and the second column is the index of the element of that array. (*i.e. [2, 3] means the 3rd array's 4th element which is [2065., 2133.]*)

I would like to get arrays from the main list wrt the index list. The codes below does the jobs rightly but inefficiently. (***out** is my expected output*)

```
out=[]
for i in range(0,len(index)):
    out.append(mainlist[index[i][0]][index[i][1]])
```

Using loops for indexing makes me feel uncomfortable. By the way, in my real data set, I am dealing with about one million rows. How can I make it faster and efficient?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First improvement that can be made - use list comprehension: out = [mainlist[index[i][0]][index[i][1]] for i in range(0, len(index)]

Comment: Thanks @Sergius but I got almost no improvement with this.